# What is an ing-form used as what appears to be a participial adjective, but for which there is no corresponding verb?

Tags: verbs

After verifying that it was a real word, I just posted a chapter named "Processioning". I have begun to wonder what kind of thing that is.  As far as I know there has never been a verb, "to procession", and "to process" is something else entirely. Yet, "they were processioning through town" makes perfect sense.

I am thinking that there may be a class of such words, apparent verb forms made from nouns. Am I misguided, or simply ignorant of what the heck that is?  It is also weird that processioning would not be used as a gerund, because the noun form is procession. I guess it could be an adjective though, "the processioning group".

edit:

- talented musicians
- an unconvincing argument
- an enterprising foreign policy
- a fun-loving guy

are sound examples with no corresponding verbs [EA].

Comment: The intransitive verb _procession_ does exist [[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/processioning)].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Do You Call It when a Noun is Used as a Verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236185/what-do-you-call-it-when-a-noun-is-used-as-a-verb)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (i) the intransitive verb procession does exist. (ii) Absent context, the PoS of "processioning" could be gerund, verbal noun or participle.

Comment: The claimed duplicate deals with verbing of nouns, conversion giving non-defective verbs. Very different. I verb, you verb .... But *I yellow-belly.

Comment: ***Processioning*** [is also a legal term:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/processioning) *(US) A proceeding prescribed by statute for ascertaining and fixing the boundaries of land.*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (i) the intransitive verb procession does exist. (ii) Absent context, the PoS of "processioning" could be gerund, verbal noun or participle.

Comment: None of your *-ing* examples display what you think they do. They all have a clear verb behind them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such words do exist, though obviously 'unconvincing' say isn't derived from a noun. Though Downing and Locke (see next link) state that derivation from a noun rather than a verb is ... at least, usual.  Examples include *enterprising, neighboring, talented*, and *skilled* [[Nordquist; ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486)]. ('Skilled' probably arose before 'skill' was commonly verbed.)

They are called pseudo-participials / pseudo-participles (and may be -ed as well as -ing types):

> - **pseudo-participial** [adjective] [not comparable]
>
> [linguistics]: Having the form of a participial of a verb, but for
> which no such verb exists. For example, for the adjective
> *yellow-bellied* there is no corresponding verb "to yellow-belly".
>
> - [noun] **pseudo-participial** [plural pseudo-participials]
>
> [linguistics] A pseudo-participial word.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pseudo-participial)]

The [Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar, p282](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lPdxvB8wAxgC&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq=%22Parasynthetic+adjectives+of+this+sort+are+especially+frequent%22&source=bl&ots=e7jDVrL9K2&sig=ACfU3U35Pv42BpCTv3HJ3PR1ZzgwFdQSHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiau-u47OGBAxW2gP0HHQ5ACrUQ6AF6BAgWEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false) similarly has:

> Participial adjectives also include words formed with the regular -ed
> or -ing forms but which lack a corresponding verb.
>
> Parasynthetic [compound] adjectives of this sort are especially frequent:
> able-bodied, half-hearted, two-faced, white-haired ...
>
> This kind (lacking a corresponding verb) is sometimes called a
> pseudo-participle.

Comment: I'd love to see some  *-ing* examples of this.

Comment: *Two-faced* lacks a verb, but *time-saving* does not. In all these cases, it's **object-verbing** in form, because you verb the object.

Comment: 'Timesave / time-save ...' does not exist as a verb. My understanding is that that is the criterion. Obviously, 'face', 'mind', take', speak' ... exist as simplex verbs.'Facing', 'saving' ... are not pseudo-participials.

Comment: That's silly. If it's a time-saving measure, you don't “❌time-save”; you simply save time. A ***man-eating tiger*** has a verb it derives from: it's *eat*. These are perfectly normal participial forms. They are not pseudos.  Maybe a *tigering man* would be pseudo since there's no verb  *to ❌tiger* to base it off of, but not a *man-eating tiger*. Just simple stuff here: an *object-participle* is a normal way to make compound adjectives from transitive verbs. It's only when there's no verb that we have what OED calls the *‑ed²* suffix; that's not a real verb then, like *rough-whiskered*.

Comment: As I say, I believe the term is used to cover not only simplex forms, but also parasynthetic adjectives where there is no corresponding **compound** verb. But this is terminology; I could be wrong. Can you find an authority deciding this issue? // In the meantime, I've removed the contentious items.